# Can $\int_0^a \frac1x [\tanh(x+b) + \tanh(x - b)] dx$ be solved?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int_0^a \frac1x [\tanh(x+b) + \tanh(x - b)] dx.$$

Mathematica can't solve it, though it can when powers of $x$ are in the numerator instead of the denominator. Does it have a closed-form solution?

Comment: There is this asymptotic https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1493507/399263, but I don't think there is a closed form for $\int \frac{\tanh x}x$.